# Layout changes animations Android

Tags: android, animation, layout, transition

I have a `RelativeLayout` which has a nested empty `FrameLayout` and a `ListView` below the `FrameLayout`. I am adding a view to the `FrameLayout` with animation (setting android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in xml) and I am doing this because I want it to appear at the top of my window. So it appears with the default fade in animation. The ListView on the other hand moves down, but it is not animated. What can I do for the ListView to slide down to its position, because this is not very good looking. If I have to change the way I define my views in the layout, that's ok also. I will consider every suggestion. Thx

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"></FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out also. Thx